# How to set current time automatically in react-flatpickr?

Tags: javascript, flatpickr

I am using `react-flatpickr` library as a date picker for my project. The problem using the library is, if I select any date it always considers time as `00:00:00`. Because of such behaviour it creates problem when users from different timezone saves the date.

**Is there any way to pass user's local time as well when user selects the date?**

I also looked into `enableTime: true` which allows to pick time as well. This option also, doesn't have any way to set current time.

Here is my code.

```
const options = {
  enableTime: false,
  dateFormat: 'd-m-Y'
};

        <Flatpickr
          placeholder="Select date"
          ref={datepickerRef}
          options={options}
          value={props.field.value ? props.field.value : ''}
          onChange={(date) => {
            let selectedDate = new Date(date[0]);
            props.form.setFieldTouched(props.field.name);
            props.form.setFieldValue(props.field.name, selectedDate);
          }}

        />
```

At 06:41 PM,

Output: `Fri Oct 11 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

Expected Output: `Fri Oct 11 2019 18:41:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the library does not support that format we can set custom time to selected date using `setHours(hours,min,sec)` native method.

Get current time and set those values to your selected date

```
<Flatpickr
          placeholder="Select date"
          ref={datepickerRef}
          options={options}
          value={props.field.value ? props.field.value : ''}
          onChange={(date) => {
            let selectedDate = date[0];
            let currentDate = new Date();
            let selectedDateWithCurrentTime = new Date(
              selectedDate.setHours(currentDate.getHours(), currentDate.getMinutes(), currentDate.getSeconds())
            );
            console.log('selectedDateWithCurrentTime',selectedDateWithCurrentTime); // Fri Oct 11 2019 19:47:53 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
            props.form.setFieldTouched(props.field.name);
            props.form.setFieldValue(props.field.name, selectedDateWithCurrentTime.toISOString());
          }}
        />
```

Check example here https://codesandbox.io/s/flatpicker-with-current-time-txdsx